# Extract highlighted scanned text/ images from pdf

Tags: pdf, highlighting

I need some tool or workaround to extract highlighted areas from a PDF.
I'm working with a scanned pdf, so no text recognition and I also need to extract highlighted images.

I tried Zotelo, Mendeley, and selecting print summary from printpdf (ctrl+p) dialog but they only work with highlighted text.

Comment: There is no tool for that, clipping the highlighted area and pasting in your summary is the only possible way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with a scanned pdf, the pdf itself contains compressed image data. It does not contain the text as such. Thus, your solution needs to:

1. Extract the image from the pdf to a image format
2. Possibly parse the text with a dedicated OCR tool

From your question it is not clear what OS and tools you have at your disposition, neither what is your scripting ability. Because of these, here's a generic answer now, and this process is quite automatable (subject to variations in the pdfs) if you need to repeat it many times.

If you are doing this by hand, the first step could be as simple as print screen and possible cropping. An alternative is to use a tool to [convert the pdf document to an image file](https://alternativeto.net/software/gimp/). Then you could crop according to your needs e.g. with [gimp](https://gimp.org/).

For the second step you can use [any OCR software](https://alternativeto.net/software/tesseract/), e.g. [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).

Comment: The highlighted area could be an image or text which was highlighted using area highlighter so this solution may be best.